# How do I run the ansible seport module in Fedora 26?

Tags: ansible, selinux, fedora-26

Running the ansible `seport` module in Fedora 26 produces the following error:

```
This module requires policycoreutils-python
```

However, `policycoreutils-python` is already installed.

```
- name: install system packages
  package: name={{ item }} state=present
  become: true
  with_items:
    - libselinux-python
    - policycoreutils-python
```

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this issue, install the `enum34` python package:**

```
- name: install system packages
  package: name={{ item }} state=present
  become: true
  with_items:
    - libselinux-python
    - policycoreutils-python
    - python-enum34
```

The `enum` package is in Python 3 but not in Python 2. The `enum34` package backports `enum` to Python 2. The root cause is this line in `setools/policyrep/util.py`:

```
from enum import Enum
```

Please check these links for more information:

- [setools commit fcadd7](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/setools/commit/fcadd71b2403856df158f387500cd33c501fb97c#diff-9197a2a06b6affeed4ab2a1896d8433eR21)
- [setools tox.ini with enum34](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/setools/blob/master/tox.ini)
- [travis-ci test on python 2.7](https://travis-ci.org/TresysTechnology/setools/jobs/269068537#L2226)
- [redhat bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1456157)